# WPF: Can not select first TabItem in TabControl with nested TabControls

Tags: wpf, events, tabcontrol, tabitem

I'm facing a strange issue with nested TabControls in WPF.

In my Home Window I need to put a TabControl inside another TabItem, in order to create different menu levels.
Since I need to have no default-selected TabItem, I'm using `TabControl.Loaded` event like so:

```
    private void TabControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TabControl)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

The issue is: first TabItem of nested TabControl is not selectable, unless selecting the second one then clicking again on the first header.

I created a sample project to demonstrate the problem.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TabControlTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControlTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Loaded="TabControl_Loaded">
            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <Label Content="Menu 1" />
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <TabControl Loaded="TabControl_Loaded">
                        <TabItem>
                            <TabItem.Header>
                                <Label Content="Sub-Menu 1" />
                            </TabItem.Header>
                            <Grid>
                                <Button Content="Button in subitem 1" Margin="82,131,553,89" />
                            </Grid>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem>
                            <TabItem.Header>
                                <Label Content="Sub-Menu 2" />
                            </TabItem.Header>
                            <Grid>
                                <Button Content="Button in subitem 2" Margin="429,69,206,151" />
                            </Grid>
                        </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <Label Content="Menu 2" />
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Button Content="Button in Hello 2" Height="NaN" Margin="274,65,54,237" Width="NaN" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If I disable the `Loaded` event, there are no issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I uploaded the sample project [here](https://mega.nz/file/VStHmKbK#v44B_8XNzfKHTmhT8joY7ofossDTGiSxkHQRGwbkLWo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling the `Loaded` event, I believe you can add an invisible `TabItem` to prevent the first "real" tab from being selected initially:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Label Content="Menu 1" />
        </TabItem.Header>
        <Grid>
            <TabControl>
                <TabItem Header="" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                <TabItem>
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <Label Content="Sub-Menu 1" />
                    </TabItem.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Button Content="Button in subitem 1" Margin="82,131,553,89" />
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem>
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <Label Content="Sub-Menu 2" />
                    </TabItem.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Button Content="Button in subitem 2" Margin="429,69,206,151" />
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Label Content="Menu 2" />
        </TabItem.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Button Content="Button in Hello 2" Height="NaN" Margin="274,65,54,237" Width="NaN" />
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Another potential workaround would be to bind the `TabControl` to a source collection using the `ItemsSource` property.

Comment: Nice workaround! I'd really like to understand why this happens. I noticed that if I click on the first tab (not working), then deactivate and reactivate the window, the tab is finally selected. I wonder if this could be a WPF-level issue or something like that.
Adding an empty collapsed TabItem completely solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle window.contentrendered and set the selectedindex to -1 on the outer tabcontrol:

```
    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tc.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

I've named that tabcontrol tc, obviously:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="tc">
        <TabItem>
```

When I handle loaded on the outer tabcontrol, the same approach works.

```
    private void tc_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tc.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It works but I noticed there's a small delay between window activation and tab de-selection, especially on low-specs machines.